# Using 2d sprite characters from asset store

Tags: animation, sprites

noob here

So I recently downloaded this asset https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/2d/characters/2d-archers-sprites-18748 
from the asset store. All the animations work great (walk, jump etc) but I do not know how to edit these. So let's say I want my character to jump from point A to point B, how would i start doing this? And would i just add the script to the animation?

Comment: Setting up a jump in Unity is something covered in dozens if not hundreds of beginner tutorials available for free, just a web search away. Can you show us how you've tried to implement this based on your research thus far, and where you're running into trouble that this wealth of tutorials wasn't able to help you with?

Comment: Do you just want to *use* the animations as-is while moving your character? (google "2D Jumping in Unity") Or do you want to edit 2D animations? (much more involved, depending on how your sprites are set up)

Comment: @DMGregory yes, you are correct, i did find a tutorial which helped me eventually with the jumoing problem; I was making a silly mistake that is why it was not working and I got frustated

Comment: @MandisaW I was initially trying to just use the animations as is and this worked okay but know even when i don't want the character to jump, it always jumps and never stands still. So if i have an idle, jump, walk animation(s) etc and they are all part of the same controller, how would I choose which actions happen whens?

Comment: @MandisaW I was initially trying to just use the animations as is and this worked okay but know even when i don't want the character to jump, it always jumps and never stands still. So if i have an idle, jump, walk animation(s) etc and they are all part of the same controller, how would I choose which actions happen whens?

Comment: Please edit your question above to ask that. Be sure you've read through tutorials on using animator controllers and methods like Animator.SetTrigger first though: we expect questions here to show research effort, and so far it still sounds like you're asking us to repeat content that's widely available in free intro to Unity guides.

Comment: @user19964 Yeah, what you're looking for is any of the lessons on Mechanim & Animation Controllers. That's a good first step.